# How to calculate R-squared after using clogit function in R

Tags: regression, r, logistic, r-squared

I am trying to calculate the R-squared value of a logistic regression model using the `clogit` function after multiple imputations with mice package in R. Here's the code for the model:

```r
fitt2 <- with(imp30, 
           clogit(Prognosis ~ stromal_TILs + hair_follicles + 
                  Upward_scatter,  strata(Set_ID)))
summary(pool(fitt2), conf.int = TRUE, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

The `pool.r.squared()` by mice package seems to work only with `lm()`. How can I obtain the R-squared value of this model?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question but you can get a pseudo R-squared with the `performance` package:

```r
library(survival)

# create data
resp <- levels(logan$occupation)
n <- nrow(logan)
indx <- rep(1:n, length(resp))
logan2 <- data.frame(logan[indx, ],
    id = indx,
    tocc = factor(rep(resp, each = n))
)
logan2$case <- (logan2$occupation == logan2$tocc)

# run model
mod <- clogit(case ~ tocc + tocc:education + strata(id), logan2)

# R2
performance::r2(mod)
```

```
> performance::r2(mod)
  Nagelkerke's R2: 0.309
```